# В чём разница между ГБ и ГиБ?

Tags: информатика

В чём разница между единицами измерения информации ГБ и ГиБ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

гигабайт GB 1000000000 байт
гибибайт GiB 1073741824 байт

Answer (score 15):

Разницы на самом деле две.

Первая из них, как и отмечено в принятом ответе, состоит в том, что термины «килобайт», «мегабайт» и «гигабайт» по рекомендации [IEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Electrotechnical_Commission) должны означать соответственно 1000, 1 000 000 и 1 000 000 000 байт. В отличие от них, термины «кибибайт», «мебибайт» и «гибибайт» должны означать 1024, 1024² = 1 048 576 и 1024³ = 1 073 741 824 байт.

В реальности же (и в этом состоит вторая разница), «би»-варианты практически не применяются, и в повседневном общении килобайт, мегабайт и гигабайт означают чаще всего (но не всегда) именно 1024, 1024² и 1024³ байт. Это создаёт путаницу, но термины наподобие «кибибайт» настолько неблагозвучны, что с этой путаницей приходится жить дальше.

Тем не менее, производители дисковых накопителей и чипов оперативной памяти часто используют для обозначения ёмкости своих устройств традиционные единицы («гигабайт»), употребляя их в смысле рекомендации IEC (то есть, у них 1 Гб = 1 000 000 000 байт). Критики утверждают, что это делается не столько для поддержки стандартизации, сколько из маркетинговых соображений.

Answer (score 0):

ГиБ (гибибайт) на  73 741 824 байта больше Гб (гигабайт). Гибибайт был разработан, чтобы заменить термин гигабайт в тех областях информатики, в которых он означал 1 073 741 824 байта, что противоречит определению СИ для префикса гига- (109 = 1 000 000 000, миллиард).