# Куда делись 44 ГБ на новом SSD под сервер Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, железо, хранение-данных, ssd

Выделенный сервер. На нем 24ГБ памяти и новенький SSD на 960ГБ , на который только что установлен Ubuntu 16.04.

```
~# df --total -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G   13M  2.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       880G  1.4G  834G   1% /
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
total           917G  1.4G  871G   1% -
```

Вижу, что 12ГБ+12ГБ+12ГБ пространства зарезервированы системой. (Кстати, объясните, пожалуйста, для каких целей каждый из них).

Далее видим оставшееся свободное пространство для данных 880ГБ - 1.4ГБ =878.6 ГБ. Но графа Avail, нам показывает, что доступно только 834 ГБ.

Вопрос: Куда делись 44,6ГБ?

Comment: 12+12+12 это в оперативной памяти, а не на SSD

Comment: Начнём с того, что в одном ГБ (гигабайте) 1000 МБ (мегабайт), а в одном гибибайте (ГиБ) 1024 мебибайта (МиБ) — поэтому размер вашего 960ГБ SSD — **894 ГиБ**

Comment: Продолжим тем, что файловая система ext4 резервирует 5% места для рута на всякий случае, а это 880*0.05 = те самые 44 ГиБ. Вы можете уменьшить резерв до 1% командой вроде `sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda3` (или отключить совсем `-m 0`, но лучше не надо)

Comment: Только не 894 а 917. 960000000/(1024*1024)=917. И там еще в total написано 917.

Comment: @coder675 960000000 это килобайты, а в байтах это 960000000000. Так что в гибибайтах получаем 960000000000/(1024*1024*1024)=894. В total не надо смотреть, там учитывается оперативная память

Comment: @andreymal в ответ же)

Comment: @edem мне лень.

Comment: @andreymal, какой такой случай может произойти, что понадобятся эти 5%? 1% не маловат будет? Негативные последствия уменьшения до 1% не предвидятся, как вы думаете?

Comment: @Ruport простые пользователи могут случайно забить место на диске целиком, а этот процент будет доступен только для пользователя root, чтобы у него осталась возможность работать в системе без получения ошибок о нехватке места на каждый чих. Значение 5% появилось во времена маленьких HDD, а для почти терабайта это чудовищно много и можно уменьшить

Comment: @andreymal ну, вы подумайте.

Comment: можно закрывать как [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/15/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нельзя, автор спрашивал вообще не об этом, а я в комментариях рассказал просто на всякий случай

Comment: @andreymal, у автора вопроса вообще смешались в кучу кони-люди. но основная «потеря» как раз на разнице между «маркетинговыми» (они же «метрические») и «айтишными» гигабайтами. а про остальных коней-людей надо отдельные вопросы задавать. так что за вторичную причину закрытия вполне сойдёт формула «слишком общий вопрос».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin автор всё-таки спрашивает про разницу между 878 и 834

Comment: @andreymal, да я-то не против: пусть третьей причиной закрытия будет дубликат про какой-нибудь вопрос, где эти самые «рутовые резервы» обсуждались (а обсуждались многократно).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я первым делом, прежде чем писать комментарии, вбил в поиск «ext4 резервирование», но там всего два результата, и оба не те

Comment: @andreymal, да, в основном об этом пишут в комментариях. но есть и в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452602/178576) (по иронии судьбы, он ещё и мой).